# How can I use Y.mojito.models in middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yui, middleware, mojito

I'm using nodejs with the mojito mvc framework.

Do I have access to some global variables from middleware? How can I use Y.mojito.models in middleware?

```
// ./middleware/mymiddleware.js
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {

    // How to use Y?
    //Y.log('fails');
    //Y.mojito.models['MyModel'].fetch(function(err, data) {
    //    next();
    //});
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend not to try to do that. Those are express middleware, they are suppose to do a quick job, sometimes async job but generally, if the request is meant to be processed by mojito dispatcher engine, you should not try to access runtime components in a middleware.

That been said, there is an internal API (that again I strongly recommend not to use) that will give you access to the global Y which holds all the YUI modules at the server side. Something like this:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
   // then `config.Y.mojito.models['MyModel'].fetch()` is available here
   return function (req, res, next) {
      next();
   }
};
```

Aside from that, if what you're looking for is a way to share models, or expose global models,  you should look at mojito-models-addon, `expose` method.

Again, the `config.Y` thing is private and we might change that at any time.

*update: in mojito there are two types of middleware, the traditional `express` middleware and the mojito middleware, which will have to be prefixed with `mojito-`, and these are the one that should expose a function that receives `config` and returns a transitional `express` middleware. Without the prefix, it will just be called per requests without preparation.*

Comment: I tried it. But the returned function is never called. The function "module.exports" is used as middleware. I configured it the following way: http://developer.yahoo.com/cocktails/mojito/docs/topics/mojito_extensions.html#middleware

Comment: Your example seems to work if I use the folder "{app-dir}/middleware" and prefix the file with "mojito-".